# How can I replace patterns using re module in python3

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x, replace

I wanted to replace certain pattern(space between alphabet) multiple times in a line. 
Here's my code :

`s = re.sub('([a-z]) ([a-z])', '\g<1>_\g<2>', 'series m coupe')`

I expected to replace *'series m coupe'* to *'series_m_coupe'*, but what I got is *'series_m coupe'*. Even I put `count=0`, it didn't work...

I guess it's because "m" is 1 syllable. when I put more than 1 syllable like *'series mini coupe'*, that worked :

```
s = re.sub('([a-z]) ([a-z])', '\g<1>_\g<2>', 'series mini coupe')
s
'series_mini_coupe'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `([a-z]) ([a-z])`, the `s m` is matched in `series m coupe` and the regex index is after `m`. So, the regex engine is looking for a second match after that letter, and can't find any.

You need to use a lookahead to match overlapping strings:

```
s = re.sub('([a-z]) (?=[a-z])', '\g<1>_', 'series m coupe')
                    ^^^     ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gN5oS7/1)

The `(?=[a-z])` lookahead will check if the space is followed with a lowercase ASCII letter, but will not consume it. In the replacement pattern, the `\g<2>` should be removed as there is no longer the second capturing group.

Comment: Wow!! What a smart, wonderful code!! Thanks, I had no idea about "lookahead". It really helpful :)